Issue with Flutter: Authorization Failed when Running flutter pub get
I'm encountering an issue while trying to run flutter pub get for my Flutter project. Here's the error message I'm getting:
Resolving dependencies...
Because flutter_application_18 depends on flutter_lints any which doesn't exist (authorization failed), version solving failed.
Insufficient permissions to the resource at the https://pub.dev package repository.
You can modify credentials using:
dart pub token add https://pub.dev
exit code 69
